# how to solve postfix errors?

Tags: centos, postfix

After following several tutorials on setting up postfix at basic level on CentOs for my VPS, continue to get the following:

```
-bash-4.1# postfix start
/usr/libexec/postfix/postfix-script: line 317: cmp: command not found
postfix/postfix-script: warning: /usr/lib/sendmail and /usr/sbin/sendmail differ
postfix/postfix-script: warning: Replace one by a symbolic link to the other
postfix/postfix-script: starting the Postfix mail system
```

In the `main.cf` below are my edits:

```
myhostname = myservername.sub.mysite.net
mydomain = sub.mysite.net
myorigin = $myhostname
myorigin = $mydomain 
inet_interfaces = all
inet_interfaces = $myhostname
inet_interfaces = localhost
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mynetworks = 192.168.0.0/16, 127.0.0.0/8
```

Also removed sendmail but haven't yet set up db, just trying to get postfix to start without errors.

Is this the problem? why are two files in red?
[image: usr/sbin]

Comment: What's the output of `which cmp`? The first line suggests to me that postfix is running sanity checks which rely on it. (Strange, I've never seen an install without it.)

Comment: the output of the command. For me, it's
`~ % which cmp` giving `/usr/bin/cmp`

Comment: I can't find what you are talking about sorry?

Comment: /usr/bin/which: no cmp in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)

Comment: Installed:
  diffutils.i686 0:2.8.1-28.el6                                                 

Complete!
-bash-4.1# postfix stop
postfix/postfix-script: stopping the Postfix mail system
-bash-4.1# postfix start
postfix/postfix-script: starting the Postfix mail system
-bash-4.1#

Comment: installing that seemed to fix it but now still have to work out subdomain stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably lacking the `diffutils` package, which will provide the `cmp` binary that postfix needs for its sanity checks.

```
sudo yum install diffutils
```

should help you on.

Comment: you were a few minutes too late with your answer :P

Comment: can u tell me mistake here pls? -bash-4.1# postconf -e postfix_mydestination = localhost burra.yabbit.net
postconf: fatal: missing '=' after attribute name: "postfix_mydestination"

Comment: @freja: Sorry, I'm not a mail person at all really.